# handle multiple xml tags in one document with php

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

i today tried to export a big xml file with php to add the content later to a mysql database. 
i got in contact with [PHP SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php) today and it worked great for just one big plot of a xml tag, but when i add more like:

```
<features>
<name>Holy moly</name>
 ....

 </features>

<features>

<name>what the...</name>
 ...

 </features>
```

my script cant handle more than one big xml "all over" tag. 
heres my php parse script:

```
<?php
include 'example.php';//heres my xml content

$features = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

/* For each <character> node, we echo a separate <name>. */
foreach ($features->properties as $properties) {
   echo "<br />".$properties->name, ' played by ', $properties->website, PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A well-formed XML document should have only one root element, encapsulating all other elements. So, I would suggest that you encapsulate the features element with a higher root element.

Comment: It isn't possible write a tag <root> at the document start (well, after the xml and doctype declarations) and close it at the document last line? If your file doesn't have gigas of data, notepad++ should open it.

Comment: I'm unsure of two approaches          
a) foreach ($root->features as $features) {    foreach ($features->properties as $properties) {   
echo "<br />".$properties->name, ' played by ', $properties->website, PHP_EOL;  
}  
}   
or b) foreach ($root->features->properties as $properties) {     
echo "<br />".$properties->name, ' played by ', $properties->website, PHP_EOL;  
}  
I think b) should do the trick, but a) is a failsafe

Comment: P.S.: Don't know how to break line at comments

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
foreach ($root->features as $features) { 
foreach ($features->properties as $properties) {
echo "<br />".$properties->name, ' played by ', $properties->website, PHP_EOL; 
 } }
```